# Unmarshalling JSON content from a a file using GO and generate .go files using the GO template package

Tags: json, go, go-templates

I am interested in reading a schemas(json formatted text file) and unmarshall it as schemas (for which i have some JSON structures defined in a .GO file) and For each type of structure in the Schema, I want to generate a corresponding .go file which has the code for performing CRUD operations using the template package (http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) to generate these files.

Example of a structure in a schema file - 
{

```
type struct XYZ {
    Type         string                 `json:"type,omitempty"`
    ResourceType string                 `json:"resourceType,omitempty"`
    Links        map[string]string      `json:"links,omitempty"`

}

The text file has a JSON structured data which is something of this form -

{
        "type": "collection",
        "resourceType": "schema",
        "links": {
        "self": "…/v1/schemas",
        },
        "createTypes": { },
        "actions": { },
        "data": [ 86 items
        {
        "id": "schema",
        "type": "schema",
        "links": {
        "self": "/schemas/schema",
        "collection": "…/schemas",
        },
         ...

     }
```

}

Could somebody help me how could i possibly generate the code for these CRUD operations for different structs using the GO template package.

Answer (score 2):

You might find `go generate` useful.

---

> [proposal: go generate](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-dev/ZTD1qtpruA8/fgJ8a0tW1xcJ)
>
> New go tool subcommand proposed for Go
>   1.4. Please see the design document and comment in this thread.
>
> http://golang.org/s/go1.4-generate
>
> -rob

---

> [Go generate: A Proposal](http://golang.org/s/go1.4-generate)
>
> Introduction
>
> The go build command automates the construction of Go programs but
>   sometimes preliminary processing is required, processing that go build
>   does not support. Motivating examples include:
>
> - yacc: generating .go files from yacc grammar (.y) files
> - protobufs: generating .pb.go files from protocol buffer definition (.proto) files
> - Unicode: generating tables from UnicodeData.txt
> - HTML: embedding .html files into Go source code
> - bindata: translating binary files such as JPEGs into byte arrays in Go source
>
> There are other processing steps one can imagine:
>
> - string methods: generating String() string methods for types used as enumerated constants
> - macros: generating customized implementations given generalized packages, such as sort.Ints from ints
>
> This proposal offers a design for smooth automation of such
>   processing.

Comment: I used to template package in GO to generate the code.I had to first write a template on my own and replace the content which needs to be generic with the struct fields using the template syntax  like {{ schema.ID }}. When the program runs like this and using the os.Create(schema.ID + ".go"), it'll generate the .GO file with the schema name.